# Seleccionar por cadena parcial en varias columnas de un dataframe de pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos y una tabla la cargo en un dataframe usando pandas, de toda la data disponible debo crear otro dataframe que contenga algunos valores especificos en 02 columnas

De la columna **StoreStatus** solo deben ser las filas que contengan CANS o FULLAUDIT y de la columna **ReasonCodeFromLHHT** las que contegan: ALT (Cero Compras), ALT (Documentada / Oral), COVID - No colabora, ALT (zero compras) y COVID - Sem cooperação.

Pero como observan en la imagen en la columna **ReasonCodeFromLHHT** no todas estan escritas de la misma forma por lo que no debe ser una busqueda exacta sino parcial por ejemplo **ALT (Document** abarcaria ALT (Documentada / Oral) y ALT (Documentadas / Orales)

""
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
""

Comment: podrias usar expresiones regulares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un approach posible sería indexar el df utilizando una máscara o vector booleano.

Primero definimos las listas con valores a incluir:

```
# valores a incluir de StoreStatus
incluir_StoreStatus = [
    'CANS', 
    'FULLAUDIT'
]

# valores a incluir de ReasonCodeFromLHHT
incluir_ReasonCodeFromLHHT = [
    'ALT (Cero Compras)', 
    'ALT (Documentada / Oral)', 
    'COVID - No colabora', 
    'ALT (zero compras)', 
    'COVID - Sem cooperação'
]
```

Después definimos la máscara: esto genera una lista del largo del df con valores True o False con los que se filtra el df. Aquí ocupamos el operador `&` como un 'y' lógico:

```
mask = (df['StoreStatus'].isin(incluir_StoreStatus) & 
        df['ReasonCodeFromLHHT'].isin(incluir_ReasonCodeFromLHHT))
```

Finalmente indexamos el df utilizando la mascara booleana `mask`:

```
df[mask]
CountryName  AuditorCode    AuditType StoreStatus        ReasonCodeFromLHHT
1   ARGENTINA          554  ALTERNATIVE        CANS  ALT (Documentada / Oral)
3   ARGENTINA          522  ALTERNATIVE        CANS       COVID - No colabora
7   ARGENTINA         2576  ALTERNATIVE   FULLAUDIT  ALT (Documentada / Oral)
9      BRASIL         2708  ALTERNATIVE   FULLAUDIT        ALT (zero compras)
```

Considerar que si la performance es importante, hay alternativas con lógica muy similar, por ejemplo, utilizando NumPy, que debieran ser más rápidas.

Respecto a la opción de búsqueda parcial, podrías ocupar la función `contains()` como elemento para construir tus máscaras:

```
mask_2 = df['ReasonCodeFromLHHT'].str.contains('ALT')
0      True
1      True
2      True
3     False
4     False
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10    False
11    False
12    False
13     True
14     True
15     True
16    False
Name: ReasonCodeFromLHHT, dtype: bool
```

Espero te sirva.